# ZFS performance: Extreme low write speed

Tags: linux, performance, zfs, openzfs

I am running a small home server. The specs are:

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 2600
- RAM: 32 GB ECC
- System drive: 128GB NVMe SSD
- Data drives: 3x 4 TB Seagate Barracuda HDD

The server runs some applications like Nextcloud or Gitea and I want to run 1-2 VMs on it. So there are some web applications, databases and VMs.

The applications and qcow2 images are stored on a raidz1 pool:

```
$ sudo zpool status
  pool: tank
 state: ONLINE
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        tank        ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz1-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdb     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdc     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdd     ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

When I used the applications in the first weeks, I experienced no problems. But since a few weeks I realized extremly low write speeds. The nextcloud instance is not very fast and when I try to start a fresh VM with Windows 10 it needs about 5 Minutes to get to the login screen.

I did some performance testing using `fio` and got following results:

| Test | IOPS | Bandwith (KiB/s) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| random read | 37,800 | 148,000 |
| random write | 31 | 127 |
| sequential read | 72,100 | 282,000 |
| sequential write | 33 | 134 |

I did some research before posting here and read that I should add a SLOG to the zfs pool for better performance with databases and VMs. But that's no option at the moment. I need to get christmas gifts first :D

But even without a SLOG I don't think these figures are correct :(

Does anyone have an idea? :)

Comment: I already disabled `atime` on all datasets and set `recordsize` to 64K on the dataset storing the qcow2 images

Comment: You should not use RAIDZ1 in any circumstances. Whenever one device fails, there is a very high risk that second drive fails during resilvering and you'll lose all your data. RAIDZ1 might also manifest in slowness like this. Use mirror instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem by myself.

I saw an article mentioning CMR (conventional magnetic recording) and SMR (shingled magnetic recording), [the latter of which offers decreased write performance](https://www.wundertech.net/cmr-vs-smr-what-is-the-best-hard-drive/). I checked my drives and I realized that I accidentally bought hard drives with SMR :(

I will keep a mirror pool until I replaced the drives with new CMR drives.
When I have the new drive I will also use a mirror pool.

Thank you all!

Comment: Good you found the solution, better would be you could shortly summarize what is the issue with SMR and link the article maybe?!

Answer (score 2):

As a first-order approximation `raidz` provides the random performances of a single disk, which for a 7.2K HDD are about 70 IOPS. Your test shows 50% less IOPS (ie: ~30 vs ~70) and this can be explained with the relatively large `recordsize` you selected.

Especially for random writes, any `recordsize` larger than 4KB is going to face considerable read/modify/write penalty. Please note that I am **not** advocating for using such a small `recordsize` on mechanical disks as it commands a very high metadata overhead, high fragmentation and (almost) no compression. As a reference, when using HDDs I leave the default (128KB) recordsize even for virtualization hosts.

You can do the following to improve performance:

- use `mirror` vs `raidz` where applicable (but you only have 3 disks, preventing the use of mirroring+striping)
- use RAW image files rather than QCOW2 (if QCOW2 files really are required, be sure to preallocate their metadata)
- try setting `sync=disabled` (but be sure to understand that in case of sudden power loss your system will lose up to 5s of written data)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and excuse me for my late reply!

I removed one drive from the system and created a mirror pool.
That improved the read speeds by about 30% as expected.
But the write speeds didn't changed :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use log-structured file system with SMR drives. It aggregates multiple small writes into a single big write, so write access is sequential mostly. With ZFS configuring huge ARC helps.